# Viewing scheduled messages with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm using the gem 'delay_job' for a project. Basically you can have a job be scheduled for the future with the attribute :run_at. What I want to do is have a view that list message to be sent, and have the option for the admin to view edit and delete them. Here is my html.

```
<tbody>
    <% @message.each do |message| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= message.body %></td>
      <% end %>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

and here is my controller

```
def schedule_message
  @message = Message.order(sort_column => sort_direction)
end
```

right now it's showing only already sent messages, like I stated before I'd like it to show messages to be sent. here is my view.[image]

Comment: Do the message objects get created as part of the delayed job? In which you'll need to loop over those instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
Message.where(["created_at >= ?", Time.zone.now]).order(sort_column => sort_direction)
```

Comment: I think your on to something but I still this error

Comment: </thead>
      <tbody>
        <% @message.each do |message| %>
        <tr>
          <td><%= message.body %></td>
  <% end %>

Comment: undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass

Comment: The above query should return an `array` with records or an empty `array`. Its not going to return `nil`. Please check the query and run it it `rails console` if necessary to see the results.